# How to create virtual scrolling for images using React js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-virtualized

Whats my requirement: i have some images in my external folder and i need to import to component and display it and also have to use **Virtual Scroll** here i have to display 1 row in div and in that 1 row have to show 5-6 images

What i did : i consumed images using context from external folder and showed images in 1 rows in div and 5-6 images but i am facing issue unable to set it to **Virtual scrolling**

as i checked react-virtualized & react-window plugin but i am not sure how my data is used in that format

After using the react-tiny-virtual-list images are getting stacked

below is my code

```
class App extends React.Component{

  state={
    Response:[],

  }
  importAll(r) {
    return r.keys().map(r);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    let data = this.importAll(require.context('./imageFolder/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
    this.setState({ Response:data})
  }





  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container" id="imagecontainer">
        <div className="viewport"> 
              {this.state.Response.map((image, index) =>    <img key={index} src={image} alt="info"></img>      )} }
           </div> 


      </div>
    )
  }


 .container {
      padding: 0% 6%;
      height: 400px;
    }
    .viewport {
      height: -webkit-fill-available;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 35px;
}


After implementing React-tiny-list
 <div id="container">
      <div id="viewport">
      <VirtualList
    height='400px'
    width='100%'
    itemCount={this.state.items.length}
    itemSize={20} // Also supports variable heights (array or function getter)
    style={{padding:'20px'}}
    renderItem={({index, style}) =>
      <div key={index} style={style}> 

        <img key={index} src={this.state.items[index]} alt="info"></img>
      </div>
    }
  />
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: change `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use the https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized plugin in this if you want to display this as table you can choose list or you can choose grid also .For you requirement i recommend using  **Masonry from 'react-virtualized'**;

below is the sample for displaying

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  CellMeasurer,
  CellMeasurerCache,
  createMasonryCellPositioner,
  Masonry
} from 'react-virtualized';

import 'react-virtualized/styles.css';

var images = [];
const columnWidth = 250;
const defaultHeight = 260;
const defaultWidth = columnWidth;

const cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
  defaultHeight,
  defaultWidth,
  fixedWidth: true
})

// Our masonry layout will use 3 columns with a 10px gutter between
const cellPositioner = createMasonryCellPositioner({
  cellMeasurerCache: cache,
  columnCount: 4,
  columnWidth,
  spacer: 27
})

function cellRenderer ({ index, key, parent, style }) {
  const datum = images[index]

  const height = columnWidth  ||  defaultHeight ;

  return (
    <CellMeasurer
      cache={cache}
      index={index}
      key={key}
      parent={parent}
    >
      <div style={style}>
        <img
          src={datum}
          style={{
            height: height,
            width: columnWidth,
            display: "block"
          }}
          alt="info"
        />

      </div>
    </CellMeasurer>
  )
}


class Grid extends React.Component{

  importAll(r) {
    return r.keys().map(r);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    images = this.importAll(require.context('../imageFolder/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div  id="container">
          <div id="viewport">

             <Masonry
            cellCount={images.length}
            cellMeasurerCache={cache}
            cellPositioner={cellPositioner}
            cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
            height={400}
            width={1320}

        />
          </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Grid;
```

I hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: Ok let me give a try

Comment: It works so this sort of format is fine but still I can make some improvement s

Comment: what sort of improvements you require ?

Comment: Some css as.the above one using it's own css so I need to check

Comment: of course the plugin gives its own css but still you can edit it

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble implementing the virtual scroll, note that the order of the imports is important when doing this, so pay heed to this - it could be contributing to your issue. (An aside: There is an [npm plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tiny-virtual-list) for implementing a virtual list.)

An overview of the import order for virtual scroll is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import {
  Grid,
  VirtualTable,
  TableHeaderRow,
} [from material ui];

import {
  your-components
} from 'your-path';
```

(above is non-specific, just a rough guide to the order)

You could also use a [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-scrollview) if you are unable to implement a "Virtual scroll". 
The following style will give you a horizontal scroll (as opposed to the default vertical), to enable you to display your images in a horizontally-scrollable row

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Scroll view is for react native right and i checked the npm plugin it some what worked but generated stacked images as result please check the updated question